# JS event handlers. Creating nice CSS button with jquery and integrating with jquery.validate and/or jquery.form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So, i'm writing a plugin using js with jQuery, that will replace all buttons (`input type=submit` and `<button>`) on my site's pages with nice buttons that look something like `<a href='#'><span class='label'>Ok</span><i></i></span>`

At the very beginning i ran into trouble: some of my buttons don't just submit the form - some are hooked with jquery.validation plug-in, some are used to do ajax calls.

So the first idea was to save all click handlers associated with the original button (`input type=submit`) somewhere and then hook them to the new button (`<a href...`). But I haven't found a way to get references to the click handlers, so here's the first question:

*Is there a way to get references to all event handlers, associated with an element?*

The second intention was to hide original button instead of replacing it with a new one and emulate a click on it when a user presses the hyperlink on a new one. This idea was ruined on the stage of implementing. When i use `$(myButtonSelector).click()`, the form gets submitted, ignoring the jquery.validation click handlers, associated with it. `$(myButtonSelector).trigger('click')` works the same way - the form gets submitted, ignoring the validation. `$(myButtonSelector).triggerHandler('click')` doesn't work at all.

*How to execute the existing click handlers?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try just copying over the events.

```
$('button').each(function(){
  var events = $(this).data('events');

  // Copied over from jQuery.fn.clone
  var newElement = // 'a' wrapper?
  for ( var type in events ) {
    for ( var handler in events[ type ] ) {
      jQuery.event.add( newElement, type, events[ type ][ handler ], events[ type ][ handler ].data );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, i'll try that.
Could you please tell me where the 'events' data field is documented? I really cannot understand, how jQuery can resolve references to event handlers.

Comment: git clone git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git - best documentation there is.

Comment: jQuery.event.add didn't work, but jQuery.bind() method does it's job.
I also have to mind, that button may have onclick attribute, that is not in the data set object and that it can have no handlers at all - in this case, you have to bind submit() to it.

Thanks.